# Spring Boot JPA Repository Fetch Join

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Java 8 Spring Boot application that uses Jpa-Hibernate to interface with our database. I am having a problem with getting the repository to fetch join complex objects in certain instances.

Here is my entity object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Foo", schema = "dbo")
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FooBId")
    private FooB fooB;

    @Column(name = "AccountNumber")
    private String accountNumber;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Here is my repo:

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Integer> {
}

@Repository
public class HibernateFooRepository extends AbstractJpaRepository<Foo, Integer> implements FooRepository {
    public HibernateFooRepository(@Qualifier("emFactory") EntityManager em) {
        super(Foo.class, em);
    }
}
```

And finally my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {
    private final FooRepository fooRepository;

    public FooController(final FooRepository fooRepository) {
        this.fooRepository = fooRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Foo>> getFoos() {
        List<Foo> foos = fooRepository.findAll();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(foos);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/create", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Foo> createFoo(@RequestBody Foo foo) {
        Foo saveEntity = fooRepository.save(foo);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(saveEntity);
    }
}
```

For some reason the `GET` method works perfectly fine. It fetches all the Foo objects and joins on the FooB by Id. However, the create method does not work.

I have found that when I do a `.findOne` as the very first repo call then it works. However, if I do ANY other repo operation then the fetch joining will not work. For example if I do:

```
repo.findOne(1); //Fetches Foo, joins on FooBId and fetches fooB
repo.save(...);
```

But if I do:

```
repo.save(...);
repo.findOne(1); //Will not join on FooBId and therefore fooB will be NULL
```

I am not understanding why the repo fails to fetch `fooB` if you call any other repo operation first. I am using `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *the create method does not work*: what do you expect it to do? What does it do instead? What are your inputs and outputs?

Comment: You are already using spring data jpa so for what you need (based on the above example), you don't need the `HibernateFooRepository`

Comment: @alltej unfortunately the application won't start up if I remove the `HibernateFooRepository` class. Spring complains about trying to autowire an interface into the controller. Therefore I have to implement the interface with a class and annotate it with `@Repository`